# Skip first child of top level divs only

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a style to all of the top-level divs within a div excluding the first one. All of attempts using `not(:first-child)` are recursive. How do to so?

```
<div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
</div>

.want-to-skip-first-a div:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: solid red 11px;
}
```

Jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GrAaA/85/

Thanks!

Comment: `.want-to-skip-first-a > div:not(:first-child)` ? I'm not entirely sure what you're after.

Comment: a quick google search would give a lot of results in SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to apply the style to all the `div` tags where you have assigned the "a" class except the first one, then you just need a minor modification to your css.

```
.want-to-skip-first-a .a:not(:first-child) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do as j08691 suggested and just use the direct child selector (`>`)

```css
.want-to-skip-first-a>div:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: solid red 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you can use the "sibling" selector (`+`)

```css
.want-to-skip-first-a .a + .a{
  border-top:11px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
    <div class='a'>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, i believe your CSS would work if you had specified the class name on the div

```css
.want-to-skip-first-a div.a:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: solid red 11px;
}
```

```html
<div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
  </div>
  <div class='a'>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any of these should accomplish what you need.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy, you're complicating.
You just need to give the class in the div's you want that css properties. 
In this case you have 6 elements, you give the class element to all of them, less than the first one

```
<div>
   <div >1</div>
   <div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>2</div>
   <div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>3</div>
   <div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>4</div>
   <div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>5</div>
   <div class='want-to-skip-first-a'>6</div>
</div>
```

[Your Solution Is Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrAaA/97/)